# Best way to denote mappings $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$, and $\mathbb{Z}[t] \to \mathbb{Z}_m[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

The mapping $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ defined by $a \mapsto a \pmod{n}$ is commonly denoted as such. Or, in the construction or interpretation of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ involving the congruence classes modulo $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, I've seen that same mapping denoted $a \mapsto [a]$, or $a\mapsto [a]_n$.

What would be the clearest way to denote a mapping $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n \leq m$ and $n|m$ and such that $a \mapsto a$ where the LHS of that mapping is interpreted as $a \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ and the RHS is interpreted as $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$?

Also, how would I denote the same kind of mapping $\mathbb{Z}[t] \to \mathbb{Z}_n[t]$ where I want $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + \cdots + a_kt^k$ to map the polynomial $p(t) = b_0 + b_1t+\cdots + b_kt^k$ where $b_i = a_i \pmod{n}$ for each $0 \leq i \leq k$? i.e. that I want the same polynomial $p(t)$ but with its coefficients interpreted in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as opposed to in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Yea I have that, I'll edit and add that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I would choose something along the line of $[a]_m \mapsto [a]_n$ for the first one, if I really wanted to specify that with symbols. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with describing the map with words, which is not uncommon at all. You are reducing mod $n$.

For the second one I would always use the standard notation

$$\overline{a_0} + \overline{a_1}t + \dotsc + \overline{a_k}t^k$$

as long as the integer $n$ is clear from the context or once again use words. You are also reducing mod $n$ in this case. If you have to vary between classes with respect to two integers $n$ and $m$ and you really do not want to describe the map with words, you could of course also use something like $[a_i]_n$ again, which already starts to look quite terrible.

Another option for both cases would be to say something like the obvious map or the canonical map from ... to ... This is also done by quite some authors.